# How to make column from a list in scala/pyspark dataframe ? Error: The feature is not supported: literal for 'List()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

`enter code here`I am practising to add a list into dataframe col. I can def udf and register and then apply on dataframe but I want to try a different approach that extracting a `list from dataframe col` and them `map it` and then `readd to the original dataframe` in new column.

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("A",1),("B",2),("C",3))).toDF("Str", "Num")
+---+---+
|Str|Num|
+---+---+
|  A|  1|
|  B|  2|
|  C|  3|
+---+---+
```

list collected:

```
scala> var ls : List[String] = df.select("Str").collect().map(f=>f.getString(0)).toList
var ls: List[String] = List(A, B, C, d)
```

Transformation:

```
def f(x : String) : String = {
  if (x=="A") {x + "100"}
  else {x + x.length.toString}
  }
```

apply transformation:

```
scala> ls.map(x => f(x))
val res95: List[String] = List(A100, B1, C1, d1)
```

add column from the list: **ERROR**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit,col}
df.withColumn("new", lit(ls)).show()

error: org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: The feature is not supported: literal for 'List(A100, B1, C1)' of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon. 

//Please correct here
```

Comment: f must return String not Unit

Comment: Thanks for that. can you please help for creating column as well

Answer (score 1):

Create the udf:

```
val myUdf = udf { x: String =>
   if (x=="A") {x + "100"}
   else {x + x.length.toString}
 }
```

and the apply to the df:

```
df.withColumn("new", myUdf(col("Str")))
```

to add a new column from a List:

```
df.withColumn("fromListColumn", array(Seq("one", "two").map(lit(_)):_*))
```